# Duplicate requests when using apollo client in electron.js

Tags: graphql, electron, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo

In electron.js I have basic component that has two useQuery hooks. When the component re-renders the hooks fire and should result in 2 calls in the network tab. However there are 3 or sometimes 4 requests. Looks like the apollo cache is not working. If remove one hook and fire the other one multiple times f.e. with lazy, there is a single network request and the cache works properly.
This issue appears in dev and in prod - after installation of the package

The component:

`const Test = () => {
console.log('rendering ....');

```
useGetUserQuery({
    variables: {
        id: 'SE',
    },
});

useTagsQuery();

return null;
```

};`

The client that is passed to the ApolloProvider wrapping the Test component

`export const useClient = () => {
const authToken = sessionStorage.getItem('token');

```
const httpLink = createHttpLink({
    uri: 'https://api',
});

const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
    return {
        headers: {
            ...headers,
            authorization: authToken ? `Bearer ${authToken}` : '',
        },
    };
});

return {
    client: new ApolloClient({
        link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
        cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    }),
};
```

};`

Not sure if this is of any value but both query responses have the same parent __typename but other than that are totally different.

When I preview the Cache tab in Apollo Devtools there is only the ROOT_QUERY and it stores only the first of the two queries from my Test component.

So far I have tried:
React 16 and 18
Removing Strict Mode
Downgrading ApolloClinet to 3.3
Changing fetch and re-fetch policies
I have tried all the solution I was able to find here

I would expect one call for each hook

Thank you

Comment: Your `useClient` hook is creating a new ApolloClient every time it is called. Are you 100% sure that component never rerenders?

Comment: Already found the culprit, it was the schema and how it uses the namespace. Was described here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63746078/apollo-client-3-0-cache-with-namespaced-queries
I was just looking in the wrong place.